# Observing changes of derived properties: CALayer KVO example

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way to observe changes in derived properties?  For example, I want to know when a CALayer has been added as a sublayer so that I can adjust its geometry relative to its (new) parent.

So, I have a subclassed CALayer, say CustomLayer, and I figured I could register an observer  for the property in init:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"superlayer" options:0 context:nil]
```

and implement `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context`.  Nothing ever happens because, presumably, superlayer is a derived property (the attr dictionary stores an opaque ID for the parent).  Similarly, I can't subclass `setSuperlayer:` because it is never called.  In fact, as far as I can tell there are no instance methods called or public properties set on the sublayer when a parent does `[self addSublayer:aCustomLayer]`.

Then I thought, OK, I'll subclass addSublayer like this:

```
- (void)addSublayer:(CALayer *)aLayer {
    [aLayer willChangeValueForKey:@"superlayer"];
    [super addSublayer:aLayer];
    [aLayer didChangeValueForKey:@"superlayer"];
}
```

but still nothing!  (Perhaps it's a clue that when I make a simple standalone test class and use the `will[did]ChangeValueForKey:` then it works.)  This is maybe a more general Cocoa KVO question.  What should I be doing?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Well, `superlayer` is defined as a `readonly` property, which means that there's no `setSuperlayer:` method. (If there is, it would be private, and you probably shouldn't use it.) If I had to make a guess, it would be that the `superlayer` property just isn't KVO-compliant. And, aside from that, I generally don't think it's a good idea for classes to observe themselves.

Maybe there's another way of doing this. When a layer is added to a superlayer, the `onOrderIn` action takes place. Now, `actionForKey:` is an instance method that gives a layer an opportunity to customize the default animations for certain properties. You could override `actionForKey:` to detect when the `onOrderIn` action takes place, do your thing, then call `super`'s implementation.

I consider this a pretty messy hack, too, though. But it should be a bit more "self-contained" than having to use custom layers for everything and messing with KVO messages.

Comment: Ooh.  I like the kCAOnOrderIn idea.  Thanks for the tip.  Will try.

At least now I know from the 2 comments so far that I'm not doing something terribly wrong, but just struggling with the lack of completeness in an API implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"superlayer" options:0 context:nil]
> ```

Don't observe yourself through KVO. Change your accessors instead.

> Similarly, I can't subclass setSuperlayer: because it is never called.

I take it you tried this and added NSLog and found that it wasn't called?

> Then I thought, OK, I'll subclass addSublayer like this:
>
> ```
> - (void)addSublayer:(CALayer *)aLayer {
>     [aLayer willChangeValueForKey:@"superlayer"];
>     [super addSublayer:aLayer];
>     [aLayer didChangeValueForKey:@"superlayer"];
> }
> ```

And the parent layer is also a CustomLayer, right? If the parent layer is a plain CALayer, anything you do in CustomLayer will have no effect.

Comment: Re "don't observe yourself through KVO", in this case the property is derived so I can't change its accessor to trap the change.

Re the 2nd part of the question: yes the parent layer is also a custom CA subclass.  That's called.  But the KVO notice isn't called.  Weird.